# How to pull all the apk at same time by adb?

Tags: adb

**How to pull all the android archive file at same time by android debug bridge?**
this is used for one android archive file:
adb pull /data/app/com.imo.android.imoim-1/base.apk E:\APK

but i want all the file same time.

Answer (score 1):

Linux and non-root solution.

Create a shell script `pm_apk.sh` with content:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f | cut -d':' -f2- | rev | cut -d'=' -f2- | rev | awk '{print "adb pull "$0}' > adb_pm.list
```

Run command `bash pm_apk.sh` to generate `adb_pm.list` file(Assume your shell is bash). Example:

```
$ cat adb_pm.list 
adb pull /data/app/~~FOOBAR==/com.azure.FOOBAR-FOOBAR==/base.apk
adb pull /data/app/~~FOOBAR==/com.adobe.FOOBAR_FOOBAR==/base.apk
....
```

Then create this python script `adb_pm_unique_output.py` with content (the "Duplicated" log is to debug to ensure no duplicated output filename when pull):

```
pkg_names = []
out_names = []
pkg_name = ''
with open('adb_pull.sh', 'w') as f_run:
    with open('adb_pm.list') as f:
        for lines in f.readlines():
            apks = lines.rstrip()
            apk_name = apks.split('/')[-1]
            pkg_name_raw = apks.split('/')[-2]
            if '-' in pkg_name_raw:
                pkg_name = pkg_name_raw.split('-')[0]
                out_name = pkg_name + '_' + apk_name
            else: # overlay
                out_name = apk_name
                pkg_name = pkg_name_raw
                if pkg_name_raw != 'overlay':
                    #print('what is this no overlay and no - ?' + repr(pkg_name_raw)) # DMService ...etc
                    if apk_name != (pkg_name_raw + '.apk'):
                        pass #    print(apk_name, '##', pkg_name_raw)
            if pkg_name in pkg_names:
                if pkg_name_raw not in ['overlay', 'framework']:
                    print(f'pkg: {pkg_name}')
                    print(f'lines: {lines}')
                    print('WARNING. Duplicated pkg name!')
            if out_name in out_names:
                print(f'out: {out_name}')
                print('WARNING. Duplicated out name!')
            pkg_names.append(pkg_name)
            out_names.append(out_name)

            f_run.write(lines.strip() + " '" +  out_name + "'\n")
```

Run command `python3 adb_pm_unique_output.py` to generate `adb_pull.sh` script. Example:

```
$ cat adb_pull.sh
adb pull /data/app/~~FOOBAR==/com.azure.FOOBAR-FOOBAR==/base.apk 'com.azure.FOOBAR_base.apk'
adb pull /data/app/~~FOOBAR==/com.adobe.FOOBAR_FOOBAR==/base.apk 'com.adobe.FOOBAR_base.apk'
...
```

Then run that script with command `time parallel :::: adb_pull.sh` to pull apks.

`time` for output spent time. `parallel` speed up the time from ~3 minutes(non-parallel) to ~2 minutes 34 seconds(parallel) in my case.

Note that few apks such as `/vendor/overlay/` get `Permission denied` because no root.

Answer (score 0):

To copy pull all the files from the directory, you can use the following command if you use adb with root permission:

```
adb pull /data/app/.
```

If you are not using adb with root permission, you need to copy all the files first to a "non-root" location and pull them from there:

```
c:\> adb shell su
root@device: / # mkdir /sdcard/data/copy_apks
root@device: / # cp -R /data/app/. /sdcard/data/copy_apks/
root@device: / # exit
c:\> adb pull /sdcard/data/copy_apks/. c:\to\your\location
c:\> adb shell rm -R /sdcard/data/copy_apks
```

Note: you need to have a rooted device or you need to be in custom recovery

Comment: "/system/bin/sh: su: not found" is coming when i am trying to execute adb shell su and  "/data/app/: 0 files pulled" is coming when i am trying to execute adb pull /data/app/

Comment: Then you don't have root access. You won't be able to pull from /data/app without root access.